# Cant use color shades on Scaffold widget Flutter

Tags: flutter

Im trying to set a color shade for my scaffold widget, and I'm getting this error.

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Color'.
>   Try defining the operator '[]'.

In a previous project that i did, I dont have this problem. 
Does anybody know what i might be doing wrong?

**Code Used:**

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black[900],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shade of Black color with `900` (maybe you were using something else in your previous project), you can use grey

```
Colors.grey[900]
```

or any other black shade like:

`Colors.black12, Colors.black26` or even `Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8)` if that suits your need.

Comment: Thankyour for the answer. 

I would like to note that the flutter error report is quite misleading.

Comment: Is there some Jira or other issue tracker link where this could be brought to attention?

Comment: You can file an issue [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues)